# Check how many blocks dogecoind downloaded

Tags: dogecoin

I just started to run dogecoind, and I am wondering how I am able to check how many blocks I have currently downloaded vs. how many total blocks need to be downloaded?

I found [this handy script for bitcoind](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10859/how-to-check-bitcoind-block-chain-download-progress-level), but unfortunately, it does not work for dogecoind.

Answer (score 1):

Using any cli-based daemon (dogecoind,bitcoind,etc.), you can use the cli `getinfo` command:

```
./dogecoin-cli getinfo
```

Will return something like:

```
{
"version" : 1080000,
"protocolversion" : 70003,
"walletversion" : 60000,
"balance" : 505658.00000000,
"blocks" : 399670,
"timeoffset" : -1,
"connections" : 7,
"proxy" : "",
"difficulty" : 9373.23745278,
"testnet" : false,
"keypoololdest" : 1404252263,
"keypoolsize" : 101,
"paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
"relayfee" : 1.00000000,
"errors" : ""
}
```