# How to check Bitcoind block chain download progress level without blockchain explorer?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, block

so my problem isn't with bitcoin particularly but with a dying altcoin, I have the same problem as [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10859/how-to-check-bitcoind-block-chain-download-progress-level).
But can't use a blockchain explorer site, since there doesn't exist one.
Is there any way to query this number from a node?